# .delegate in combination with fancybox

Tags: jquery, delegates, fancybox

I have a problem with fancybox, which I want to apply on images in a div, which is dynamically changing it's content with .replaceWith. The code looks like the following:

```
$(document).load('fancybox', function() {
        $('.various4').fancybox({
                'width'             : 800,
                'height'            : 750,
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });
    });
```

This applies to the following HTML:

```
<a class="various4" href="http://xy//index.html"><img height="400" width="600" src="bg.jpg"  class="hoverbild" /></a>
```

As I am using a hover-function with jquery, and I am changing the content of the div, I used the following code to provide the hover-effect working after changing the content of the div:

```
$(document).delegate('.hoverbild', 'hover', function(){
    $(".hoverbild").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","bg-hover.jpg");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","bg.jpg");
    });
});
```

This works without problem. But now, if want to tell the fancybox-part to delegate, it doesn't work at all. There is no error warning, it's just ignored.

```
    $(document).delegate('.various4', 'fancybox', function(){
        $('.various4').fancybox({
                    'width'             : 800,
                    'height'            : 750,
                    'autoScale'         : false,
                    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                    'type'              : 'iframe'
                });
        });
```

What am I missing? I tried to use .live instead, which doesn't make a difference, though.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the `delegate()` function and the first parameter of the `live()` function specifies which type of event to bind the function to. `'fancybox'` is not an event, and that is why it is ignored.

You can do the following,

```
$('.various4').live('hover', function() {
  $(this).fancybox();
});
```

Which should work, because before the user clicks on the image they must hover over it which will then call `fancybox()` on that image.

Alternatively you could create your own event and call it on every image that is created after you run `replaceWith()`.

After `replaceWith()` simply do something like,

```
$('.various4').trigger('apply_fancybox');
```

And then have,

```
$('.various4').live('apply_fancybox', function() {
  $(this).fancybox();
});
```

You'll probably need to trigger this event for any initial images that are not dynamically created with `replaceWith()`.

And yet another way of doing this, the simplest of all, why not just use `$('.various4').fancybox()` after you call `replaceWith()`?

Comment: I see! I thought fancybox is interpreted like an event. I am going to work on the different solutions, true, the last seems to be the most reasonable. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

`$('selector').fancybox()` binds opening the box as a click handler, if you want to open the fancybox manually use `$.fancybox()`

```
$(document).delegate('.various4', 'click', function() {
    $.fancybox({href: $(this).attr('href')});
    return false;
});
```

That will work for an inline iframe if you want to open an image use:

```
$(document).delegate('.various4', 'click', function() {
    $.fancybox($(this).attr('href'), {type:'image'});
return false;
});
```